# Restrict WordPress backend access, without conflicting forms

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a standard form in WordPress and I am struggling with restricting access to the WordPress backend and properly working forms, because the forms are processed over wp-admin and if this is restricted, forms are not processed.

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Restricting backend access:

```
// Restrict users to enter backend
add_action('init', 'restrict_backend_access');

function restrict_backend_access() {
    if (is_admin() && current_user_can('subscriber') && !(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)){
        wp_redirect( '/dashboard/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? I know that this is possible, because I build it many times, but this time something is different and I don't know why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find correct code as below:

```
add_action( 'init', 'restrict_backend_access' );

function restrict_backend_access() {
    if( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) && !( defined( ‘DOING_AJAX’ ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );  
        exit;
    }
}
```

You can set redirect as per your requirement.
As for example replace

```
wp_redirect( home_url() )
```

with

```
wp_redirect( '/dashboard/' );
```

Comment: This would appear to only stop backend access for a person who is logged in i.e. a person can just logout and then gain access to the backend. To stop everyone from accessing the wordpress backend add a rule to your server configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your code and I have still the problem that frontend forms are not processed.

Comment: Are you checking with the Subscriber user or admin user?

Comment: I found out, that my form doesn't have the input field "admin_post_request". If I change it to a custom input field with a $_POST it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden field to the form

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
...
<input type="hidden" name="admin_post_request" value="1" />
</form>
```

then use it to bypass the redirection

```
add_action( 'init', 'restrict_backend_access' );
function restrict_backend_access() {
    if( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) && !( defined( ‘DOING_AJAX’ ) && DOING_AJAX && !isset( $_GET['admin_post_request'] ) ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );  
        exit;
    }
}
```